# How to type a special mathematical expression in the context of matrix computations?

Tags: tikz-cd

I am writing lecture notes for a course I am teaching. A Module on Matrix Computations involves a special mathematical expression and I have no clue how to typeset in LaTeX. I have enclosed an image of this calculation and I request your kind help how to typeset it. There is a special type of arrow in this image, and I have never seen it listed in the standard list of arrow commands in LaTeX. I thank you for the kind help!

[image]

Comment: Looks like a job for `tikz-cd`.

Comment: This looks like a _do-it-for-me_ question. Show your efforts or what you have already tried.

Comment: Also, it has _nothing_ to do with `latex3`. Please add sensible tags.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need this often you might want to approach this more automated.

### Code

```
\documentclass[varwidth]{standalone}
%\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, chains}
\newcommand*\matrixcomputation[2][]{%
  \tikz[
    start chain=going right, node distance=.5cm and 1cm,
    every join/.append style={arrows={Latex[scale width=.7]-}},
    n/.style={align=right, text depth=+0pt},#1]
    \foreach[count=\i from 0, evaluate={\tw=max(width("$\a$"),width("$\b$"));}]
      \a/\b in {#2} \path[text width=\tw]
       node[n, on chain, join=by {path only, to path={(\tikzchainprevious.center)
         to[bend left] node[above]{$x_{\i}$} (\tikzchaincurrent.center)}}] {$\a$}
        \unless\ifnum\i=0 ([yshift=+.5ex]\tikzlastnode.south west)
          edge[every join] ([yshift=+-.5ex]\tikzchainprevious'.north east)\fi
       node[n, below=of \tikzchaincurrent](\tikzchaincurrent'){$\b$}
        \unless\ifnum\i=0 ([yshift=+-.5ex]\tikzlastnode.north west)
          edge[every join] ([yshift=+.5ex]\tikzchainprevious.south east)\fi;}
\begin{document}
\matrixcomputation{1/2, -1/-2, 3/1, 1/2}

\bigskip
\matrixcomputation{15/-2, 172/-3, 1/2, 5/10, 666/777}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: You have my official permission to change your user name to Lord TikZ. 

Answer (score 5):

It might require some tweaking, and there are probably more elegant solutions for shifting the labels:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}

\[\begin{tikzcd}[cells={nodes={text width=width("$-0$"), align=center}}]
   1 \ar[rd] \ar[r, bend left, "x_1" above, phantom]
        & -1 \ar[rd] \ar[r, bend left, "x_2" above, phantom]
            & 3 \ar[rd] \ar[r, bend left, "x_3" above, phantom]
                & 1
\\
    2 \ar[ru]
        & -2 \ar[ru]
            & 1 \ar[ru]
                & 2
\end{tikzcd}\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Dear friend, thanks a lot! I tested your answer, it compiles beautifully and exactly as I wished.. I like to know if it is possible to increase the size of "x_1", "x_2" and "x_3" ? Thank you!

Comment: @Dr.Sundar Doing `labels={font=}` as an option to the `tikzcd` environment should do it. The “labels” are typeset in `\scriptstyle` by default.

Comment: Alternatively, throw in `\textstyle` in front of each `x_i`.

Comment: I'd place the labels as a separate arrow: `\ar[r, bend left, "x_1" above, phantom]`. the `phantom` style also reset the `\scriptstyle` setting.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel Good idea, wasn’t sure about this. Probably there is also an elegant solution to make the three crossed arrows look more alike. It could probably be done by `\smash`’ing and `\math(c/l/r)lap`’ing each of the entries, but are there better ways?

Comment: @Gaussler The most annoying thing is not that the minus adds depth (that can be solved with a `cells={execute at begin node=\vphantom{$-$}}`) but that they are just wider which means the arrows start/end at the upper/lower edge where as with the smaller ones they meet at the sides. (Add `cells={nodes=draw}` to see this.) Maybe just forcing `start anchor=south east, end anchor=north west` (and the appropriate for the other one) would be a good start as long as the nodes in each column are equally wide. Otherwise, maybe `cells={nodes={text width=width("$-0$"), align=center}}` …

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel The last suggestion seemed to work out well, so I added it to the answer.

Answer (score 3):

With `{NiceMatrix}` of `nicematrix` and TikZ.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix,tikz}

\begin{document}

\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.4}
\begin{NiceTabular}{*{7}{p[c]{5mm}}}
\RowStyle{\small}
  & $x_1$ & & $x_2$ & & $x_3$ \\
  $1$ & & $-1$ & & $3$ & & $1$ \\ 
  $2$ & & $-2$ & & $1$ & & $2$
\CodeAfter
  \begin{tikzpicture} [->, shorten > = 3pt, shorten < = 3pt]
  \draw (2-1) -- (3-3) ; 
  \draw (3-1) -- (2-3) ; 
  \draw (2-3) -- (3-5) ;
  \draw (3-3) -- (2-5) ; 
  \draw (2-5) -- (3-7) ;
  \draw (3-5) -- (2-7) ; 
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{NiceTabular}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]